# Specific JSON parsing issue - array of varying objects - Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I have a block of JSON I have to consume. I have no control over the shape of the JSON data.

Let's say I have a response blob that looks like this:

```
{
"resultStatus" : 1,
"resultEntities" : [...]
}
```

Inside the resultEntities array, there are two distinct objects; one type is always at index 0, essentially a header for everything that follow, and indices 1...-> contain another type (I can control the type I ask for). There's *some* overlap of fields between the two objects, but only a couple of fields out of a total of about 30 fields.

```
{
"rectype" : 1,
"recname" : "header",
"companyname" : "Smithson & Jones",
"companyId" : "q1w2e3r4",
...
}
```

and

```
{
"rectype" : 2,
"recname" : "detail record",
"locationId" : "123 Miami Warehouse",
"shelvingUnits" : 654,
...
}
```

My receiving object looks basically like this:

```
struct APIResponse : Decodable {
let resultStatus : Int
let results : [...] //<--- and there is the issue
```

I don't think I can define my receiving object so that results[0] always tries to parse to header, and all other ones parse to details, right?

I obviously can't do something like this (pseudocode, I know this won't compile - it's just here to clarify what I am dealing with):

```
let results : [ 0 = header type, ... = detail type ]
```

or

```
let results[0] : Header 
let results[...] : Detail
```

and so forth.

So, should the object that is the array in results just be an amalgamation of header and detail with all fields (except known overlappers) being optional?

I hope I'm explaining this well enough.

Thoughts? (happy to answer any questions to narrow in on the details if needed, and update the question accordingly)

Comment: You need a custom `init(from decoder)` to handle your specific case. But is "Header" or other defined for instance according to `rectype` value? That could be one way to differentiate them... And ideally, you'd want: `let header: Header; let other: Other`, ie two different var in APIResponse? What should look like you ideal structure?

Comment: Not sure if I get it right, do you have a header and a detail type in the array or is it one header type and one out of many detail types?

Comment: Rectype (and overall shape), but yeah, it seems I can count on that being fixed values for the types. There's some... ahem... fluidity between the docs I have and the actual data I'm receiving so far. But it's "close enough for government work". :) 

I'm getting the data object back from the API call, and I'd rather *not* pick apart all the text in the json. This is stupid easy in something like JavaScript, but getting from data object to something traversable without using a parsing object seems to be either no possible, or not obvious is the docs.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, in results, index 0 is always the header, and indices beyond are the detail type. The detail type is always the same type, no matter how many records.

Comment: @Larme, to further clarify, in something like Flutter/Dart I'd just decode to a map, spin through the map and try-parse each element to the appropriate type(s) I expect, and process on pass/fail. Unless I'm mistaken, Swift doesn't provide a decode to just a traversable map/dictionary/array, right? Decode always wants to go to a defined type...?

Comment: Ugh, I feel like a newbie; I've been head down and deep in Flutter for the past like three years and coming back to swift is such a breath of fresh air, but it's full of scents I have to get used to again. (sigh)

Comment: Use https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: @ChrisH, following on from your last but one comment, Swift does sort of provide that functionality, although in a different way, by using an enum with associated values.  eg. `enum HeaderDetail, case header(Header), case  detail (Detail)` and then determining which enum variant it is in the `'init(from decoder)` and then your `let results:  [HeaderDetail]`.  This allows  for strict type conformance while accommodating the differet payloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using only `Codable`, with a custom `init(from:)` where we use an unkeyed container for decoding the content of the array. Note that the header value has been moved out of the array and into its own property in the `Result` struct

```
struct Result: Decodable {
  let status: Int
  let header: Header
  var entities: [DetailRecord]
  
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case status = "resultStatus"
    case entities = "resultEntities"
  }
  
  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    status = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .status)
    var nested = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .entities)
    header = try nested.decode(Header.self)
    
    entities = []
    while !nested.isAtEnd {
      let detail = try nested.decode(DetailRecord.self)
      entities.append(detail)
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you just want a quick-and-dirty solution you can use `JSONSerialzation`

```
do {
  let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String: Any]
  
  if let entities = dictionary["resultEntities"] as? [Any], !entities.isEmpty {
    let header = entities.first!
      print(header)
    
    let details = Array(entities.dropFirst())
    print(details)
  }
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

Of course this will be more cumbersome when accessing individual properties compared to having predefined types that conform to Codable.

One way to use `Codable` here is to first convert the `header` and `details` variables to json data object and then use a decoder to convert them to proper objects

```
let detailsData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: details)
let headerData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: header)

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let headerObject = try decoder.decode(Header.self, from: headerData)
let detailsArray = try decoder.decode([DetailRecord].self, from: detailsData)
```

Comment: Awesome. I was just looking at the JSONSerialization before circling back at this. Thanks so much! This pretty much nails it. if I can peel out the data for each item, I can try-parse/try-deserialize it, and use the objects once formed from that. Thanks so much. Marking this as the accepted answer. This is exactly what I was looking for, but I wasn't making the connection. I think I was assuming JSONSerialization was simply an older version of the json decoder or something.

#mentalblock